# TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. [Selenium and Firefox only]

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, firefox

Hi we are getting the following error if our page is loaded. This occurs with firefox only and is not always reproducable but it still occurs regularly:

```
JavaScript error: https://localhost:60663/consent-ui/js/bootstrap.min.js, line 6: TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
JavaScript error: https://localhost:60663/consent-ui/js/show-session-timeout-warning.js, line 5: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
JavaScript error: https://localhost:60663/consent-ui/js/accept-documents.js, line 1: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
JavaScript error: https://localhost:60663/consent-ui/js/disable-process-buttons.js, line 1: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

We are using the Thymeleaf Framework to generate our HTML and the main-template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link data-th-href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link data-th-href="@{/css/default-style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script data-th-src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script data-th-src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <section data-layout-fragment="content"></section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now we created the following unit-test class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import de.governikus.autent.consent.ui.setup.ConsentUiTest;

@ActiveProfiles({"auto-generate-database"})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
            classes = {SpringBootInitializer.class, WebAppConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {// TODO comment
                                  "server.servlet.session.timeout=65",
                                  // TODO comment
                                  "session.timeout.warning.threshold=49"}
                    locations = {"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:application-test.properties"})
public class SessionTimeoutWarningTest extends AbstractUiTest
{

  private static final String CUSTOM_CONTROLLER_PATH = "/custom-controller";

  /**
   * context path to overview endpoint on helper controller
   * {@link de.governikus.autent.consent.ui.projectconfig.MessageSourceTest.CustomController#loadOverviewPage(boolean, boolean, String, String)}
   */
  private static final String OVERVIEW_PATH = CUSTOM_CONTROLLER_PATH + "/custom-overview";

  private final String PATH_OF_FIREFOX_DRIVER = "D:\\Konfigurationen\\geckodriver.exe";
  private final String PATH_OF_CHROME_DRIVER = "D:\\Konfigurationen\\chromedriver_96.exe";

  /**
   * used to read the keys from the resource bundles
   */
  @Autowired
  private MessageSource messageSource;

  private WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeEach
  public void init()
  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", PATH_OF_FIREFOX_DRIVER);
//    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", PATH_OF_CHROME_DRIVER);
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
     options.setHeadless(true);

    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

//    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//    options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
//    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  }


  @AfterEach
  public void tearDown()
  {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  void TestSessionTimeoutWarningDialog() throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
    driver.get(getApplicationUrl(OVERVIEW_PATH));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15));

    {
      final WebElement timerFragment = wait.until(webDriver -> webDriver.findElement(By.id("timer")));
      Assertions.assertFalse(timerFragment.isDisplayed());

      wait.until(webDriver -> timerFragment.isDisplayed());

      Assertions.assertTrue(timerFragment.isDisplayed());

      WebElement renewSessionButton = driver.findElement(By.name("dialog-accept-button"));
      renewSessionButton.click();
    }

    {
      final WebElement timerFragment = driver.findElement(By.id("timer"));
      Assertions.assertFalse(timerFragment.isDisplayed());

      wait.until(webDriver -> timerFragment.isDisplayed());

      WebElement abortButton = driver.findElement(By.name("dialog-decline-button"));
      abortButton.click();
    }
  }

}
```

with Chrome anything works fine and we never get any problems. The problem occurs with firefox only. We are not able to figure out what is causing this problem. The problem does not only occur if selenium is used. It also happens in on rare occasions in production environment...

Comment: sounds like some scripts are being loaded before jQuery... why that is I'm not sure, but the middleware may be doing something funny... try adding the scripts right before the </HTML> tag.  Ex: <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></html>

Comment: I already tried this too but it did not change the results.

Comment: You'll want to do some debugging... view the page source in the browser and double-click on the jquery link... make sure it appears.  Also right-click and inspect... check for any duplicates... (might be some header or footer that's also loading scripts...)  You may also be able to check the load order in the browser's dev tools...